# How to find the max file size in a hdfs directory

Tags: command, hdfs

I want to find the max size of files in a HDFS directory. Does anyone have any idea how to find it? I'm in Hadoop 2.6.0.

I found `hadoop fs -ls -S /url` which can `Sort output by file size` from [Hadoop 2.7.0 document](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#ls), but it's not supported in 2.6.0. So is there any similar function that can sort output files by size? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `hdfs fsck` command to get the file sizes.

For e.g., when I execute `hdfs fsck /tmp/ -files`, then I get the following output:

```
/tmp <dir>
/tmp/100GB <dir>
/tmp/100GB/Try <dir>
/tmp/100GB/Try/1.txt 5 bytes, 1 block(s):  OK
/tmp/100GB/_SUCCESS 0 bytes, 0 block(s):  OK
/tmp/100GB/part-m-00000 107374182400 bytes, 800 block(s):  OK
/tmp/100GB/part-m-00001._COPYING_ 44163923968 bytes, 330 block(s):
/tmp/10GB <dir>
/tmp/10GB/_SUCCESS 0 bytes, 0 block(s):  OK
/tmp/10GB/part-m-00000 10737418300 bytes, 81 block(s):  OK
/tmp/1GB <dir>
/tmp/1GB/_SUCCESS 0 bytes, 0 block(s):  OK
/tmp/1GB/part-m-00000 1073741900 bytes, 9 block(s):  OK
/tmp/1GB/part-m-00001 1073741900 bytes, 9 block(s):  OK
```

It recursively lists all the files under `/tmp` along with their sizes.

Now, to parse out the file with max size, you can execute the following command:

```
hdfs fsck /tmp/ -files | grep "/tmp/" | grep -v "<dir>" | gawk '{print $2, $1;}'  | sort -n
```

This command does the following:

- `hdfs fsck /tmp/ -files` - It runs HDFS file system check on the folder `/tmp/` and seeks report for each of the files under `/tmp/`
- `grep "/tmp/"` - It greps for `/tmp/` (the folder which we want to search). This will give only files and folders under `/tmp/`
- `"grep -v "<dir>""` - This removes the directories from the output (since we only want files)
- `gawk '{print $2, $1;}'` - This prints the file size ($2), followed by the file name ($1)
- `sort -n` - This does a numeric sort on the file size and the last file in the list should be the file with the largest size

You can pipe the output to `tail -1` to get the largest file.

For e.g. I got output as:

```
107374182400 /tmp/100GB/part-m-00000
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to find which is max `hdfs dfs -ls -h /path | sort -r -n -k 5`

Answer (score 0):

Please try below command.

> hadoop fs -du `Folder` | sort -n -r | head -n 1